Visual studio 2022, find in entire solution, exclude sourceserver
Not sure how/when this started, but when I use Find->Entire solution I get duplicate results from something called "SourceServer" in my %AppData% folder.


I want "Entire solution" to search in my source code (second result in the picture above), not "SourceServer". Can I specify that somehow?
Using Visual Studio 2022, v17.8.6

A possible workaround I found:
If instead of CTRL+F, I use CTRL+SHIFT+F, to get the full search window, I get the option to uncheck "Include miscellaneous files":

This has the effect of returning only source code results instead of the "SourceServer" duplicates.
No such option exists for quick find.
